# Creating a Field-Based Hyperlink in Desktop 10.7.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hyperlink, identify

To start off, most of my end-users are using ArcDesktop 10.7.1.  Under the layer Properties-Display, there is a way to add a hyperlink to the layer using a script. We have a link to our Register of Deeds that uses the book and page in the URL.  I would like to take this URL and replace the book and page entries with the attribute fields that contain this information.

For Example:

*From this*

http://rod.waynegov.com/resolution/LandRecords/protected/v4/SrchBookPage.aspx?bAutoSearch=true&bk=1482&pg=344&idx=CRP

*To this*

[http://rod.waynegov.com/resolution/LandRecords/protected/v4/SrchBookPage.aspx?bAutoSearch=true&bk=[DEEDBOOK1]&pg=[DEEDPAGE1]&idx=CRP](http://rod.waynegov.com/resolution/LandRecords/protected/v4/SrchBookPage.aspx?bAutoSearch=true&bk=%5BDEEDBOOK1%5D&pg=%5BDEEDPAGE1%5D&idx=CRP)

The process of doing this inside a pop-up in ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online is easy.  However, I would like to mimic this using the Identify tool or at least the Hyperlink tool.

Comment: Have you tried typing [hyperlink](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm) into the help file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have answered my own question.  I found a similar script where the person posting was looking for a way to link to a file location based on an attribute. ([Python Field Calculating for Document Hyperlink?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72248/python-field-calculating-for-document-hyperlink)) Taking that script, I was able to modify this script to create URL location instead of a file location.  Script as follows:

```
import webbrowser
def OpenLink ([DeedBook1],[DeedPage1] ):
  Hyper1 = "http://rod.waynegov.com/resolution/LandRecords/protected/v4/SrchBookPage.aspx?bAutoSearch=true&bk="
  Hyper2 = "&pg="
  Hyper3 = "&idx=CRP"
  path = Hyper1+[DeedBook1]+Hyper2+[DeedPage1]+Hyper3
  webbrowser.open(path)
  return
```